# Finding out the constant term in cumulative distribution function.

Tags: probability-theory

Let$$F(x)=\begin{cases} 0,\ if\ x<0\\ \frac{x^2}{10},\ if\ 0\le x<1\\\frac{x+2}{8},\ if\ 1\le x<2\\ \frac{c(6x-x^{2}-1)}{2},\ if\ 2\le x\le3\\ 1,\ if\ x>3 \end{cases}$$ Find the value of $c$ for which $F(X) $is cumulative distribution function. Also evaluate $P(1\le x\le2)$.

I find out $c$ by $P(x\le3)=1\\ \implies \frac{c(6\cdot3-3^{2}-1)}{2}=1\\ c=\frac{1}{4}$ is it correct? I am asking it because this is a mixed distribution and it is very likely that I have made a mistake which I am not able to figure out and for the other part $P(1\le x\le2)=P(x=1)+P(1<x\le2)-P(x=2)\\ =\lim_{x\to 2^{-}}F(x)-\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}$ if I use this result for jump probability $P(x=a)=F(x=a)-\lim_{x\to a^{-}}F(x)$ thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cumulative must be right-continuous, and yours is $1$ for $x>3,$ hence by right continuity must be $1$ when $x=3.$ The definition at $x=3$ gives $4c,$ so you're right that $c=1/4.$

For the point $x=1,$ the probability $P(x=1)$ is $F(1)-F(1-)$ where the second means limit as $x \to 1^{-}.$ In your case $F(1)=3/8$ while $F(1-)=1/10,$ making $P(x=1)=11/40.$ You now only need $P(x=1)+P(1<x\le 2)$ for $P(1 \le x \le 2),$ and there should not be a subtracted $P(x=2)$ at the end as you now have it.

Comment: thanks for answer I was bit confused with this one as it is a mixed distribution. so,the $P(1<x\le 2)=F(2)-F(1)=\frac{7}{8}-\frac{3}{8}$ it does'nt matter  that there is a jump at $x=2$???

Comment: It doesn't matter because $F(2)$  must be computed from your fourth formula (using $c=1/4$) and that will include the jump. So $7/8-3/8$ is correct for $P(1<x\le 2).$ Don't forget to add here the $P(x=1)=11/40$ to get $P(1 \le x \le 2).$

Comment: yeah get it thank you very much.